# mysql dynamic pagination select

Tags: mysql, dynamic, pagination

I'm having a bit trouble with making a logic for dynamic paging in mysql.

Here is the concept, which I minimize my case.
User has its own id from 1 to 10 
Item has its own id from 1 to 10
so each user can have 10 items.

If I say I selected the all item list from the register day, it would be like

```
index|user|Item
-----------------
1    |0   | 4
2    |1   | 6
3    |2   | 3
4    |1   | 5
5    |0   | 3
6    |3   | 5
```

and so on..

So If I select only 5 then the next page should be the offset 5 * 1
And next next page offset should be 5 * 2

This is working ok until another record came into the table while I am selecting next table.

So let say two new records are inserted after I selected first page. Then the next page has two duplicate records from the first page!

```
index|user|Item
-----------------
1    |9   | 7  <-- new two records inserted
2    |5   | 6
3    |0   | 4  <-- old page starts here
4    |1   | 6
5    |2   | 3
6    |1   | 5
7    |0   | 3
8    |3   | 5
```

How should I manage this dynamically changing data records with pagination? Or is there preferred logics to control this situation?

Comment: Your options would be to cache the results from the entire query on the server side, which is costly, ugly, and doesn't scale well, or to just allow those new entries to naturally flow into the result set.  If you poke around, you will see many sites going with this latter option.  Your users should ideally know that new hits may appear, perhaps somewhat infrequently, and that the same item appearing on the next page is nothing to be alarmed over.

Comment: Good example of a site which does this: Stack Overflow.  Hunt for questions and you will see this behavior in action!

Comment: I can't find a good example perfectly fits to mine.
although Im sure it is definitely a fitting model for online shopping mall where each user can upload their own selling item pieces. I just can't find ...

Comment: I think what Tim is referring to is if you look at the latest mysql (for example) questions on SO and then go to the next page, you may see the same questions at the top of this second page as where on the first page.  They are not duplicates, they are simply the same questions that have moved down the list of latest questions.